# How can I fix an invalid arugement operator in Java?

Tags: java, debugging, operators, invalid-argument

I'm struggling to debug my code. There is this one error after getting my instance and trying to substract 1 from my instance variable the code give me an error. I tried to debug many times but I couldn't figure it out. The error is invalid arguement to operation ++/--

```
   game.setNumHealthPotions(game.getNumHealthPotions()--); // The Second game.getNumHealhPotions has the error.
```

2nd error

`game.setNumHealthPotions(game.getNumHealthPotions++);`

My setters and getters both lines

```
public void setNumHealthPotions(int numHealthPotions){
    this.numHealthPotions = 1;
}

  public int getNumHealthPotions(){
    return numHealthPotions;
}
```

Comment: Not sure about using ++ or -- directly on the method call - but it looks like your setter is always going to make th e value 1, regardless of whether you can get the operation to work. Just an idea - could you just create new methods `addHealthPotion()` and `consumeHealthPotion`?

Comment: In the `setNumHealthPotions()` setter method, the line: `this.numHealthPotions = 1;` should be: `this.numHealthPotions = numHealthPotions;`.

Answer (score 2):

`++` and `--` are assignment operators. You can't assign a value to a method. You'll have to call both `get` and `set` to read and assign:

```
game.setNumHealthPotions(game.getNumHealthPotions() + 1);
```

Or you can add an increment method if it's a common use case:

```
public int incrementNumHealthPotions(int increment) {
    return this.numHealthPotions += increment;
}
```

Called like this:

```
game.incrementNumHealthPotions(-1);
```